Writing to application insights from a Phyton Azure Function App
I am trying to add logs with custom dimensions to the trace table in application insights. I have code below working but it writes to the dependency table. Any pointers how to write to traces and metrics?
import azure.functions as cho
from azure.monitor.opentelemetry import configure_azure_monitor
from opentelemetry import trace

tt = cho.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=cho.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@tt.route(route="http_trigger")
def http_trigger(req: cho.HttpRequest) -> cho.HttpResponse:
    configure_azure_monitor(connection_string="ai conn str")
    ri_ch = trace.get_tracer(__name__)
    with ri_ch.start_as_current_span("This is a Log") as val:
        val.set_attribute("who", "rithwik")
        print("Hello Rithwik Bojja, the logs are Logged")
        return cho.HttpResponse("This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.",status_code=200)


Are you checking for the app running locally?

Its works both locally and in azure. But it write to ther dependcies table and I would like to have it in traces.

Ok..Checking from my end..

@Thomas Segato Are you trying to get the custom Dimensions in the application insights as shown in this.

I am trying to add a trace to the trace table with custom dimensions, and write a custom metric with a value of example 3 to the metric table. I cant seem to figure out of your sample how you create a custom metric.

I just tested the traces part that works now! I am only trying to figure out how the metrics part is working I cant find any thing in your code writing a custom metric?

I modified your code to include a logger and attributes for the request to add logs with custom dimensions, capturing both traces and metrics in Application Insights for the function.
    logger.info("Hello Kamali", extra={"custom_dimension": "Kam_value"})
        # Added attributes for the request
        span.set_attribute("http.method", req.method)
        span.set_attribute("http.route", "/http_trigger")
        span.set_attribute("http.status_code", 200)
        span.set_attribute("custom_dimension", "Kam_value")
        span.set_attribute("who", "Kamali")

function_app.py :
import logging
import azure.functions as func
from azure.monitor.opentelemetry import configure_azure_monitor
from opentelemetry import trace
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace import TracerProvider
from opentelemetry.trace import SpanKind
from opentelemetry.sdk._logs import LoggingHandler
 
configure_azure_monitor(connection_string="<AppInsightsConneString>")
 
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
handler = LoggingHandler()
logger.addHandler(handler)
 
app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
 
@app.route(route="http_trigger")
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    """
    Handles the HTTP trigger and logs telemetry to Application Insights.
    """
    logger.info("Hello Kamali", extra={"custom_dimension": "Kam_value"})
    tracer = trace.get_tracer(__name__)
    with tracer.start_as_current_span("HTTP Request", kind=SpanKind.SERVER) as span:
        span.set_attribute("http.method", req.method)
        span.set_attribute("http.route", "/http_trigger")
        span.set_attribute("http.status_code", 200)
        span.set_attribute("custom_dimension", "Kam_value")
        span.set_attribute("who", "Kamali")
    return func.HttpResponse(
        "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.",
        status_code=200
    )

host.json :
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": ""
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  }
}

requirements.txt :
azure-functions
azure-monitor-opentelemetry
opentelemetry-api
opentelemetry-sdk
opentelemetry-semantic-conventions

Query to get traces :
traces
| where message == "Hello Kamali"
| project timestamp, message, customDimensions


Query to get metrics :
customMetrics
| project timestamp, name, value, customDimensions


Traces in Transaction Search :


Thanks alot appreciated. I will try it out. What part of the code add metrics?
